# Построить поразрядную (OR, AND ....) таблицу использую метод Integer.toBinaryString

Tags: java

Проблема собственно в том, что двоичный код отображается неправильно , как можно исправить используя всё тот же Integer.toBinaryString

```
public class Bitwise1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 6;
    int c = a | b;
    int d = a & b;
    int e = a ^ b;
    int f = ~b;
    System.out.println("a = " + Integer.toBinaryString(a));
    System.out.println("b = " + Integer.toBinaryString(b));
    System.out.println("a | b = " + Integer.toBinaryString(c));
    System.out.println("a & b = " + Integer.toBinaryString(d));
    System.out.println("a ^ b = " + Integer.toBinaryString(e));
    System.out.println("~ b = " + Integer.toBinaryString(f));
}
```

И заменить в идеале c,d,e,f на одну переменную z

Comment: Необходимо доработать вывод так, чтобы для положительных
чисел выводились все незначащие нули, соответствующие разрядной сетке.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

```
String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(123)).replace(' ', '0')
```

Формат `%32s` даст строку, дополненную слева пробелами до длинны 32 символа, `replace` заменит эти пробелы на нули. Длина 32 используется потому что `Integer` в Java хранится в 32-битном представлении.